# SSH with EOF correctly sets $PATH, but why doesn't it work without EOF?

Tags: oracle, unix, ksh

I'd like to understand why ssh doesn't set the $PATH to whatever is determined in .profile, but seems to do it when ssh uses EOF.

I'd like to run this line in my script:

```
DIR_EXPANDED=`ssh $TOADDRESS "$(typeset -f get_dir); get_dir $DIR $DBNAME"`
```

Where `get_dir` is defined like so:

```
function get_dir() {
  DIRECTORY_NAME=$1
  DBNAME=$2

  if [ -z "$DIRECTORY_NAME" ]; then
    echo "Enter Directory Name:"; read DIRECTORY_NAME
  elif [ -n "$2" ]; then
    . oraenv $DBNAME
  fi
  DIRECTORY=`sqlplus -s '/ as sysdba' << EOF
  set pages 0 head off feed off

  select directory_path from all_directories where directory_name='$DIRECTORY_NAME';

EOF`

  echo $DIRECTORY;
}
```

However, running the script results in the error

```
ksh[10]: .: oraenv: cannot open [No such file or directory]
```

Which I've found is because the path is not correctly set when ssh'ing as demonstrated by this:

```
ssh $TOADDRESS 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

Through trial and error I've found that this works:

```
TODIR_EXPANDED=`ssh $TOADDRESS << EOF
  $(typeset -f get_dir); get_dir $TODIR $TODBNAME
EOF`
```

Can someone explain why ssh works this way? As well as how/if it would be possible to use the one-liner I first described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ssh HOST command`, a non-interactive shell is loaded, which does not read the `.profile` for login shells or `.kshrc` for interactive shells.

If you use `ssh HOST` it starts an interactive shell (albeit without a pseudo-TTY allocated) and reads `.kshrc` (or similar, depending on the actual shell spawned), and then continues reading commands from standard input.

So, if you wish to make the functions available, you can do it like this:

```
DIR_EXPANDED=$(ssh $TOADDRESS ". ./.kshrc; $(typeset -f get_dir); get_dir $DIR $DBNAME")
```

(I’ve also changed the deprecated form of command substitution (using the grave accent) to the modern/POSIX form, as this fixes some bugs.)